# Most efficient way to modify character mesh at run time

Tags: unity, performance, 3d-meshes

What is the most efficient way in unity to alter the mesh of a character in this scenario:

When the player pick up an item:

-A part of the mesh should be replaced, for example, the left arm is swapped by a robotic, rock, wood etc... arm.

-The animations are the same.

-Other parts may change in a different way, for example, left arm stone right wood.(This happens in a different pick up later)

-There is no problem if the game slows for a sec as this not happen "in action".

One more thing:

In general terms, what are the thing to consider when doing these modifications in terms of performance?(Such as polygons of the mesh, resolution of textures...)

Will many changes end up in consuming memory or other resources?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by changing a part of the mesh? Like you actually want to cut off that part and splice in a new one ?

Comment: @UriPopov or anything with te same visual effect and "good" performance